# 1D manifold is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ or to $S^1$

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In his ODE classic V.I. Arnold considers *easy to see* (*легко видеть*) that every one-dimensional (connected and without boundary) differentiable manifold is either diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ (if it is not compact) or to $S^1$ (if it is compact).

Is it indeed that easy? Can this be shown using elementary tools?

Answer (score 5):

I think Milnor's "*Topology from a Differentiable Viewpoint*" (accessible online) has a proof of this in the appendix. The proof is pretty simple, but uses one slightly technical lemma. I would say the Theorem is easy to *see* since the idea is straightforward, but requires slightly more work to *prove*.

[Here it is](http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/dedo/top%20diff/Milnor%20J.%20Topology%20from%20the%20differentiable%20viewpoint%20(Princeton,%201965).pdf). See page 55.

Comment: It is indeed shown there - Elementary proof, but not short (as I had imagined.)