# smooth structure on a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Why there is a unique smooth structure (choice of a smooth atlas) up to diffeomorphism on the real line? Can someone please send a proof, thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by smooth structure on a manifold?

Comment: when do you say two smoth structures on a topological space are isomorphic?

Comment: It is still unclear. Are you asking for a proof of "Every smooth 1-dimensional manifold which is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}$ is actually diffeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}$"? You can find a proof of this in Milnor's book "Topology from Differentiable Viewpoint" (Appendix). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901770/1d-manifold-is-diffeomorphic-to-mathbb-r-or-to-s1/901773#901773